# Surface area of $2x+y+2z=16$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Find the surface area of the part of the plane $2x+y+2z=16$ bounded by the surfaces $x=0, y=0$ and $x^2+y^2=64$

I recognised this as the region in the first quadrant in the $xy$ plane of $x^2+y^2=64$. After parametrising where i let $v=x$ and $u=y$, my double integral was $\iint_V \,du\,dv$ where $u$ ranged from $-\sqrt{64-x^2}\cdots\sqrt{64-x^2}$ and $v$ ranged from $0\cdots8$. Evaluating this gave $64\pi$, which is incorrect. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't just use *any* parametrising. What would happen if you took $v=2x$ and $u=4y$? Or $v=x+y$ and $v=x-y$? To give some intuition, the problem is that "infinitesimal parallelogram" obtained from projecting $dudv$ on the plane is not the "standard", so to say, infinitesimal square. -- Apart from that, your $u$ should only range over positive values, shouldnÄt it?

Comment: That is true. But I still don't know how to solve this problem. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the constraints you are given create a domain on the $xy$ axis. Given this, consider the height of plane: $$z = \frac{16-2x-y}{2}.$$
We can now use the following result (see [here](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/surface/surface.html)) to calculate the surface area of some surface $f(x,y)$ over a domain $D$ in the $xy$ plane:

The surface area of $f(x,y)$ over a domain $D$ is given by $$S = \int \int_D \sqrt{[f_x]^2+[f_y]^2+1} dA$$ where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, respectively.

Given how in our problem $f(x,y)= \frac{16-2x-y}{2}$, the partial derivatives are $f_x = -1$ and $f_y= -1/2$. Notice the integrand is a constant (i.e. $\sqrt{1+1/4+1}=3/2$). Now, draw a picture of what $D$ looks like in the $xy$ plane. It is a quarter of a circle with radius 8. Given this information, $\int \int_D dA$ is quarter of the area of a circle with radius 8. Therefore,

$$S =  \int \int_D \sqrt{[f_x]^2+[f_y]^2+1} dA = \frac{3}{2}\int \int_D dA = \frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{\pi 8^2}{4} = 24\pi $$

Comment: The answer in the book is $24\pi$

Comment: Also, what are you bounds for $x$ and $y$? I used $-\sqrt{64-y^2}\leq x\leq\sqrt{64-y^2}$ and $0\leq y\leq 8$, but this yields an incorrect answer.

Comment: You mentioned it correctly that it is in the first quadrant. So, the bounds are: $0\le x\le 8, 0\le y\le \sqrt{16-x^2}.$ So the integral is: $\int_0^8\int_0^{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\frac32dydx$.